# Slicing for arbitary numpy array of arbitrary dimenions

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Suppose I have an ndarray of numpy of arbitrary dimensions, and I would like to extract the first two frontal slices of this array. What is the best way to proceed? For example, if the input array A is 5 dimensional, I want to extract A[:,:,0:2,1,1]. Likewise if it is 3 dimensional, I would like to extract A[:,:,0:2], and if it is 6 dimensional, A[:,:,0:2,1,1,1], etc...

Comment: I would use the following: `A[(slice(None),)*2+(slice(0,2,1),)+(1,)*(A.ndim-3)]`. So one can use code to construct tuples of any number of indices and then use these within an index. `:` is only a syntactic sugar for `slice(None)`

Comment: Ok this seems like an acceptable answer to me

Comment: ```np.s_``` is shorthand for slice, ex. ```np.s_[0:2:1]``` is shorthand for ```slice(0,2,1)```.